# How to refer to a method name from with a method in Python?

Tags: python, methods, introspection

Say I have the following class defined with the method `foo`:

```
class MyClass:
    def foo(self):
        print "My name is %s" % __name__
```

Now when I call `foo()` I expect/want to see this printed out

```
My name is foo
```

However I get

```
My name is __main__
```

And if I was to put the class definition into a module called `FooBar` I would get

```
My name is FooBar
```

However if I do

```
m = MyClass()
print m.foo.__name__
```

I get exactly what I want which is

```
My name is foo
```

Can someone please help explain why `__name__` refers to the module and not the method name ?
Is there an easy way to get the method name?

Many thanks

Comment: why do you need to do this? what problem are you solving?

Answer (score 11):

This does what you're after:

```
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo

class MyClass:
    def foo(self):
        print "My name is %s" % getframeinfo(currentframe())[2]
```

Comment: While this is correct, there's no reason to prefer it over just typing 'foo' in the function body without a lot more information from the OP.

Comment: Cool, wonder if one could make a decorator that does this somehow... At least after the decorated method has been run. Maybe you could inspect the method decorated.

Comment: @Skurmedel: `def with_name(fn): return lambda *args, **kwds: fn(fn.__name__, *args, **kwds)` (eat that, SO comment formatting)  You'd have to change the function to know it's being wrapped (the name is the first arg and self/cls comes second).

Comment: Yeah that would do it.... maybe print fn.__name__ before or afterwards. I don't know what he wants really :)

Comment: What do you propose the decorator would do? A function already has a `__name__` property, the problem is that its hard to access from within the function itself (if I understood the question correctly).

Comment: @mizipzor: Print the name... but I'm not interested in what he wants, I was pondering the alternatives.

Comment: @mizipzor: Yes, you understood what I was having trouble with. Since a function has a __name__ property, I thought that this would be in scope of the function and easy to access.  For trace purposes I was hoping to refer to __name__ from within the function and therefore not worry if the function name ever changed.  Some nice answers here recommending inspect, but I was hoping that it would be a lot more straightforward to do.

Comment: @ephesian: See my answer, its very straight forward to access the name of a function. But thats outside the scope of the function and that way you actually type the name of the function anyway (something you wanted to avoid?). Its a bit of a loophole, accessing the function without typing its name. Using **inspect** is, as far as I know, the most straight forward I know to do what you want.

Comment: @mizipzor: Typing the name of the function in the source code isn't more straight-forward? (The OP is asking how to print the name of the function; trying to use some special magic to get it dynamically is just his failed attempt.)

Answer (score 4):

Names always refer to local variables or (if one doesn't exist) then global variables.  There is a a global __name__ that has the module's name.

```
class MyClass:
  def foo(self):
    print "My name is %s" % MyClass.foo.__name__
```

Of course, that's redundant and almost entirely pointless.  Just type out the method name:

```
class MyClass:
  def foo(self):
    print "My name is %s" % "foo"
    print "My name is foo"
```

Comment: @Skurmedel: That's always possible, and hurts them more than it does me (through upvotes in response it's net win for me, even gameable), but if I have missed something, I really want to know about it.

Comment: Yeah I understand, I'm fine with downvotes as long as somebody state their concern as well.

Comment: @Roger Pate: If I change the method name, I would not want to spend time in tracking down and change every occurrence of the method name inside the method. For example, consider a logging or debug statement, which would you prefer :   "entering method : foo" v/s "entering method : %s" % inspect.stack()[0][3]

Answer (score 3):

`__name__` refers to the module because [that's what it's supposed to do](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html). The only way to get at the currently running function would be to introspect the stack.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain it quite well so I contribute with a more concrete example.

**name.py**

```
def foo():
    print "name in foo",__name__

foo()
print "foo's name",foo.__name__
print "name at top",__name__
```

**Output**

```
name in foo __main__
foo's name foo
name at top __main__
```

**name2.py**

```
import name
```

**Output**

```
name in foo name
foo's name foo
name at top name
```

Notice how the `__name__` refers to built-in property of the module? Which is `__main__` if the module is run directly, or the name of the module if its imported.

You should have run across the `if __name__=="__main__":` snippet.

You can find the [relevant docs here](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html), go check them out. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use introspection with the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module.

```
import inspect

class MyClass:
    def foo(self):
        print "My name is %s" % inspect.stack()[0][3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [the `inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html).

Try:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def foo():
...     print inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe())[2]
...
>>> foo()
foo
```

or:

```
>>> def foo2():
...     print inspect.stack()[0][3]
...
>>> foo2()
foo2
```

Answer (score -2):

This will do it:

(You need to refer to `self.__class__._name__`.)

```
class MyClass:
    def foo(self):
        print "My name is %s" % self.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: The desired behavior, as shown in the example, is printing 'foo' (the method name) not 'MyClass'.